# D3 - set axes with percent scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am attempting to create a scatterplot whereby the dimensions of the appended svg element are set by percent (so it takes up say 50 or 100% of the screen rather than X number of pixels).

Then I want to populate the svg element with circles whose positions are scaled to be in between 0 and 100 and set as a percent as well, like so: `.attr('cx', function(d){return xScale(d[0]) + '%'})`

This approach works for setting the circle positions, but I cannot get the correct scaling on the axes. I think they are set via the transform element, and this does not want to take `%` as part of an argument.

See the js fiddle here with a full example: https://jsfiddle.net/s01pg3fa/5/

The axes are not scaled correctly to fill out the entire svg element. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the client size of the svg and use it in the axis scales:

```
var svgClientSize = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect();
```

Using it on the axis scales:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d[0]})])
            .range([padding,svgClientSize.width-padding])
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d[1]})])
            .range([svgClientSize.height-padding,padding])
```

In this case, you do not need the '%' for the circles

Here is the updated js fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/q7xm8n73/1/

Comment: Do you know why the `axisBottom` is still showing up on top?

Comment: @moman822 The axis are always drawn at origin. The orientation on the axis only sets the placement of ticks and text. You need to add a translation transform on the parent element to change its location.Updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/q7xm8n73/3

Comment: This matches the bounding size properly at render time but not afterwards, where percentages are automatically rendered relative to the current window size at any given time.